# Reference type of derived class in base class

Tags: python

I'm wondering if there is a way to make the referencing of static variables more convenient in a base class by defining some type of static reference to the derived class type?

Note: code edited after posting

```
class base:
    MainType = None
    StaticVariables = xyz

    def Func(self):
        base.MainType.StaticVariables = 0

class derived(base):
    base.MainType = THISCLASS # pseudo code - no idea how to do this
```

I hope this isn't too confusing. I've read that you need to use `type(self).StaticVariables` to access any static variables, so I was hoping there may be some way to record the derived class type ahead of time to make them more accessible. Is something like this possible? Or is it a bad idea? I'm also curious to know if its possible to access the type of a class that is being defined. Is there any equivalent to 'self' for types (rather than instances) while outside of functions?

Edit: Have yet another question in case anyone is browsing by and sees this. When a base class defines a static variable, does this static variable get duplicated for each derived type, or does only one version of it exist regardless of the number of derived types?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. `base.MainType` is one of `base`'s attributes, not `derived`'s. If you try to assign two different values to it from two different classes, one of those values will be lost. Also, `Func` should be some sort of instance, static, or class method; it currently isn't. It's not clear what you're trying to do, so it's not clear what sort of method `Func` should be, but a class method seems the most likely.

Comment: Sorry, I was being rushed when I posted the question. It should have been `def Func(self)` As for the same variable in both classes not making sense, that is primarily just me not knowing what I'm doing. The `base.MainType = THISCLASS` line inside of derived was meant to be pseudo for assigning a base class variable to the derived class type. Although I'm not sure if the variable is duplicated for each derived class, or if only one of it will exist. If only one, it won't work at all. If more than one, then it should probably be more like `MYCLASS.MainType = MYCLASS`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, this is what `classmethod` is for:

```py
class Base():
    name = 'base'

    @classmethod
    def say_hi(cls):
        print(f'Hi from {cls.name}!')

class Derived(Base):
    name = 'derived'

Base().say_hi()
Derived().say_hi()
```

Output:

```
Hi from base!
Hi from derived!
```

Instead of taking a reference to the current instance, in the form of `self`, `classmethods` take a reference to the *type of the current instance*, through some nice decorator magic. This lets you call them like normal methods without having to scatter `type(self)` all over the place.

Comment: I was aware of class methods, but I haven't made much use of them yet. It may be what I need. I will try to make it work. Thanks! BTW, class methods would only be useful in situations where you don't need access to both instance variables and static variables, right?

Comment: @Robert You can refer to static variables with `cls`; in fact, that's what I did there.

Comment: What I meant to ask was if class methods are useful only when you are dealing exclusively with static variables? If I need to access variables from the instance and the class at the same time, would I use a class method for that? Or would the normal flow be to separate things so that class methods only deal with static variables? I'm going to read up on them to see if I can learn more. Thanks again.